# insert timestamp oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following format:

```
    CREATE TABLE perflog(
REQ_TIME TIMESTAMP,
RESP_TIME TIMESTAMP,
OPERATION VARCHAR2(50),
STATUS_CODE VARCHAR2(10),
STATUS_BODY VARCHAR2(30)
);
```

-I want to insert a timestamp in the following format: e.g. 2020-07-27T23:33:41.427330

-I'm getting the following error:

```
SQL> insert into perflog(REQ_TIME) VALUES(2020-07-27T23:33:41.427330);
SP2-0552: Bind variable "33" not declared.
```

I don't get how to declare the timestamp in order to insert dates like the above. Sorry if it is a noob question but I'm a begginer.

Comment: Use single quotes.  I would recommend `VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2020-07-27T23:33:41.427330')`.

Comment: Unlike INTEGERS, Strings and dates need to be wrapped in single quotes as dates are basically strings until they are converted to DATES by the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply wrapping your value in single quotes isn't enough:

```
insert into perflog(REQ_TIME) VALUES('2020-07-27T23:33:41.427330');

ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

The actual error you get will depend on your session's NLS settings (and it's possible it would work - for you, if you set your session up in a certain way - but then not necessarily for anyone else.)

Oracle has timestamp literals which you can use instead of `to_timestamp()`, but unfortunately they don't allow the "T":

```
insert into perflog(REQ_TIME) VALUES(TIMESTAMP '2020-07-27T23:33:41.427330');

ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

and you can't remove it within the call (e.g. with replace) as that then isn't a literal; so you would have to change the "T" to a space externally:

```
insert into perflog(REQ_TIME) VALUES(TIMESTAMP '2020-07-27 23:33:41.427330');
```

If you're stuck with a string with that format then use an explicitly `to_timestamp()` call to convert your string to the data type you want, supplying the matching format mask, including a [character-literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A) `"T"':

```
insert into perflog(REQ_TIME)
VALUES(TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-07-27T23:33:41.427330', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF6'));
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7d99506df6778ad992b6bd17c82bd4a2)

It's worth noting that timestamps (and dates) do not have a specific human-readable format when stored in the database. Oracle uses one of several internal representations, depending on the flavour of datetime you're using. Your client, IDE or application will format that as a readable string when you query the data, usually using your session NLS settings again. To get the data back as a string in a specific format you should use `to_char()` with the appropriate format supplied.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9d00d54b08ea10fc473f58d7c20de861) with some examples.

Comment: Hi, I want to use the timestamp as it is.

Comment: @Horia - I'm not sure what you mean. You're starting from a string, not a timestamp, based on the code in your question (even though that's missing single quotes). If you're stuck with that string (with the T in the middle) then you need to use `to_timestamp()` to convert it to an actual timestamp value to match your table column definition.

Answer (score 2):

Use a timestamp literal using a space character instead of a `T`:

```sql
insert into perflog(REQ_TIME) VALUES( TIMESTAMP '2020-07-27 23:33:41.427330');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7b0f49064f3c405d098ae6ebbdc8440b)